# Cannot add buildConfigField in productFlavors

Tags: android, gradle

In my android{} section I tried to put two different build types for may free and paid app.

Sadly I'm getting gradle error:

> Gradle 'android-Transport' project refresh failed: Build script error,
>   unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'buildConfigField()'!  Possible
>   causes could be: - you are using Gradle version where the method is
>   absent - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method - or
>   there is a mistake in a build script

This is my android{} section in gradle build:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        free {
            packageName "pl.grzeslowski.transport.free"
            buildConfigField "transport.product_flavors.MonetizationType" "MONETIAZATION_TYPE" "transport.product_flavors.MonetizationType.FREE"
        }

        paid {
            packageName "pl.grzeslowski.transport.paid"
            buildConfigField "transport.product_flavors.MonetizationType" "MONETIAZATION_TYPE" "transport.product_flavors.MonetizationType.PAID"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my console log:

> Executing tasks: [:transport:compileDebugJava]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.8.3/gradle-0.8.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/22.5.3/lint-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.8.3/builder-0.8.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/22.5.3/lint-checks-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/22.5.3/sdklib-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/22.5.3/ddmlib-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/0.8.3/builder-model-0.8.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/22.5.3/manifest-merger-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/22.5.3/sdk-common-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.8.3/builder-test-api-0.8.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/common/22.5.3/common-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/22.5.3/lint-api-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/22.5.3/dvlib-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/22.5.3/layoutlib-api-22.5.3.pom
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.8.3/gradle-0.8.3.jar
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/22.5.3/lint-22.5.3.jar
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.8.3/builder-0.8.3.jar
>   Download
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/22.5.3/lint-checks-22.5.3.jar
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'D:\Programowanie\GitProjects\transport\android-Transport\transport\build.gradle'
>     line: 77
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':transport'.
>
>   > Could not find method buildConfigField() for arguments [transport.product_flavors.MonetizationType] on
>   >     GroupableProductFlavorDsl_Decorated{name=free, minSdkVersion=-1,
>   >     targetSdkVersion=-1, renderscriptTargetApi=-1,
>   >     renderscriptSupportMode=null, renderscriptNdkMode=null,
>   >     versionCode=-1, versionName=null,
>   >     packageName=transport.free, testPackageName=null,
>   >     testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null,
>   >     testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null}.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 9.781 secs

Comment: Have you checked if your syntax for the `buildConfigField` lines is indeed correct? I think you may be missing some commas in between the strings.

Comment: buildConfigField there should be 3 strings. I dont know if the packages is needed.

Comment: As I said, the strings need to be separated by commas (`,`).

Comment: Adding commas works :). Thanks. If you put it into answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The correct syntax for the `buildConfigField` lines is:

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "MY_FLAG", "true"
```

In other words, the strings need to be separated by commas.

Comment: How can get same thing in case for different flavour. I'm getting same error log if i defined variable for different flavour. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

buildConfigField ("transport.product_flavors.MonetizationType", "MONETIAZATION_TYPE", "transport.product_flavors.MonetizationType.FREE")