# Error:(21, 0) Gradle DSL method not found:

Tags: android, gradle

This is the full text of the error:-

> Error:(21, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildConfigField()'

Possible causes:

> The project 'Sunshine2' may be using a version
>   of Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
>
> The build file
>   may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply
>   Gradle plugin

I'm using gradle 2.4 with Android Studio 1.4. I don't know what is causing the problem or how to fix it. A little help please.

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267365/cannot-add-buildconfigfield-in-productflavors

Comment: You have to provide your build.script content. Seems, you have some syntax problem

Comment: GMB - I was missing a comma. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line of code calling the BuildConfig was missing a comma:

```
buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY'  'MyOpenWeatherAPIKey'
            }
```

It now reads like this:

```
buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY',  'MyOpenWeatherAPIKey'
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the parenthesis while copy pasting your MyOpenWeatherAPIKey

Initially it looks like

```
buildTypes.each    {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherAPIKey
}
```

After you copy your MyOpenWeatherAPIKey from https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys it should like

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
```