# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method buildConfigField() android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on an online course and i had problem with this code

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0', DARK_SKY_KEY
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0', FLICKR_API_KEY
    }
}
```

but i got error like below:

```
Error:(22, 0) Could not find method buildConfigField() for arguments [String, b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0, BuildType_Decorated{name=DARK_SKY_KEY, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}] on BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=C:\Users\pc\.android\debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=C:\Users\pc\.android\debug.keystore, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true}, embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Weather-master\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Comment: post FLICKR_API_KEY value as you define @ALI GHASSAN

Comment: its same error i get

Comment: are you define DARK_SKY_KEY and FLICKR_API_KEY in gradle.build file? @ALI GHASSAN

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267365/cannot-add-buildconfigfield-in-productflavors , It may help you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to add fields to all build types, you should use this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...

        buildConfigField "String", "DARK_SKY_KEY", '"b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0"'
        buildConfigField "String", "FLICKR_API_KEY", '"b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0"'    
    }
}
```

Comment: I was missing a comma.  Gradle didn't provide a very helpful error message.

Answer (score 4):

**use**

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
  buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField ("String", DARK_SKY_KEY, "\"b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0\"")
            it.buildConfigField ("String", FLICKR_API_KEY, "\"b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0\"")
                  }
}
```

**instead of**

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
 buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0', DARK_SKY_KEY
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'b35f87cc72b82388ed9276e41fd55dd0', FLICKR_API_KEY
         }
}
```

if you not define **DARK_SKY_KEY** in file then use **"DARK_SKY_KEY"**

might be helpful to understand.